# Photoshop Scripting (JS): Duplicate layer set and subs

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script, jsx

I would like to duplicate a layer set and all it's contents (layers + layersets) via Photoshop scripting (JS).

Is it possible to completely clone a layer set out of the box, or does anyone known of a known script that suits that purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layerset object has a duplicate method on it - so it is just a matter of running something like this:

```
 app.activeDocument.activeLayer.duplicate()
```